# JavaScript. Не работает функция в Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

Добрый день! Столкнулся с такой проблемой:

1. Есть событие

   ```
   window.addEventListener('click', shot, false);
   ```
2. В функции shot есть метод

   ```
   function elementClick(){
       var classArr = [];

       var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
       classArr = target.classList;
       if (classArr[0] == 'display__gunman'){
           return true
       } else {
           return false
       }
   }
   ```
3. В функции shot он срабатывает

   ```
   if ((timeShot < gunmanTime(level)) && elementClick(document.onclick) ){
       pseudoElementHidden();

       playerShot();
       stoptimer();
       resettimer();
   }
   ```

Как можно изменить метод `elementClick`, чтоб он работал в Firefox

Comment: что значит не работает: не заходит в обработчик, падает с ошибкой? что-то еще?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добрый день, Вместо `elementClick(document.onclick)` используй `elementClick(event)`.

```
function elementClick(event){
    var classArr = [];

    var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
    classArr = target.classList;
    if (classArr[0] == 'display__gunman'){
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
var shot = function(event){
  if (elementClick(event) ){
        alert('in');
  }
}
window.addEventListener('click', shot, false);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ebxL19md/1/)